# Windows batch file, wait for command to finish?

Tags: windows, batch-file, wait

I can't seem to figure this out.

I am creating a live site and deploying it online

batch file:

```
START cmd /K "runas /user:administrator & cd C:\users\MyName\dropbox\!!GIT_HUB_REPOS_ALL\tangycode.github.io & hexo generate & hexo serve --draft"


START /wait "" http://localhost:4000/
```

The thing is running the command `hexo generate & hexo serve --draft` takes about 5-10 seconds, time varies. Ideally I want to wait for this to occur before going to live site at http://localhost:4000

Some reason this windows batch command just automatically opens up localhost:4000 right away though

Answer (score 8):

I would use /B to stay in the same process and /wait tot wait until the first command is finished. You don't need the /wait in the second line unless there are more commands to follow. If this doens't work, experiment with leaving the cmd /K away. Since runas is an executable and the batch waits until it is finished it's possible you can let away the start command all together.

If all this doesn't work insert 5 ping commands, that is the classic way to wait for ± one second.

```
START /B /wait "runas /user:administrator & cd C:\users\MyName\dropbox\!!GIT_HUB_REPOS_ALL\tangycode.github.io & hexo generate & hexo serve --draft"


START /B "" http://localhost:4000/
```

Comment: I tried running this but my command prompt simply just sits there and doesn't do anything. No error codes or anything

Comment: what exactly dit you try, I sugges here a number of things..
first try the runas part on itself without start in a console, only thereafter try it in a batch

Comment: I copy pasted your code inthe first instance. Then in my original file I removed the /wait command. I also tried /B, but for some reason it would always run the command in the same folder as my batch file.

Comment: /K was the only thing that worked for me opening up a new cmd prompt

Comment: opening up another prompt makes for not being able to wait until it is finished, you would have to go with the pings to time the second command to start

Answer (score 2):

I'll take a stab at this, *(completely untested)*.

```bat
@Echo Off

(Set SrcDir=%UserProfile%\dropbox\!!GIT_HUB_REPOS_ALL\tangycode.github.io)

If Not Exist "%SrcDir%\" Exit/B
Start "" /D"%SrcDir%" /Wait /B RunAs /User:administrator^
 "Cmd /C Start /Wait hexo generate & Start hexo serve --draft"

Start http://localhost:4000/
```

Comment: I tried running this but it requested me for admin password, even though I'm the admin :s

Comment: You used the command, I just copied it from your opening post, _(apart from my inadvertent use of a capital **A** instead of **a**, now changed)_.